# BlackBerry J2ME vs HTML Javascript framework like PhoneGap

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mobile, cordova

A client wants a blackberry application for listening live radio for his  radio station. We focused on iPhone development. I know Java language have done several projects. However haven't tried yet J2ME. Which do you recommend J2ME or HTML Javascript framework like PhoneGap or any other cross platform framework? What are the advantages and disadvantages of them? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable with Java Swing or other Java UI programming then going with native is probably a great idea.

If you are more comfortable with HTML, JavaScript and CSS then use PhoneGap. If you are planning on deploying your application to more than one platform then definitely use PhoneGap. PhoneGap also allows you to write native BlackBerry Java code and integrate that with the HTML / JS code in case the specific APIs you need are not exposed.

With the imminent release of BlackBerry OS 6 things should get a lot better on that platform for both PhoneGap (since the browser is now WebKit based) and for native Java programming.

There are many other comparisons between PhoneGap and X on stackoverflow, though most other cross platform frameworks don't support BlackBerry.

Answer (score 1):

- J2ME:  Blackberry supports this (and is fact still the BB's core), however it's a rapidly aging platform.  You can't do many interesting things in BB without the proprietary APIs.
- Phonegap:  Haven't used it myself but I've heard so-so things about it.  High footprint, lowest-common-denominator etc.